# When does the adapter implicitly refresh itself?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When does the RecyclerView.Adapter<~> refresh itself implicitly and how I can detect whether a refresh is occcurred or not?

Comment: Never.  You have to explicitly refresh it.

Comment: does onBindViewHolder calls itself when I lock and unlock the device, being at the same adapter screen?

Comment: Not unless you tell it to.

Comment: which property do I hav e to set for this?

Comment: Post some code please. I think something might be happening in your onResume method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RecyclerView`s do not refresh by themselves. When you change the data which populates the `RecyclerView` you have to call the function `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score -1):

mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(0,mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());